# WooCommerce orderby rand not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Our product template displays four cross sells after adding a product to cart. If the product doesn't have four cross sells defined then any gaps are filled with products that have been marked with a "generic cross sell" custom field, in a random order.

```
remove_all_filters('posts_orderby'); // suggested by other answers
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'posts_per_page' => $gaps_to_fill,
    'post__not_in' => $posts_to_exclude,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'is_generic_cross_sell',
            'compare' => '==',
            'value' => '1'
        )
    )
);
$generics = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $generics->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $generics->have_posts() ) : $generics->the_post();
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product-modal' );
    endwhile; 
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

If I run print_r($generics) the query looks like:

```
WP_Query Object ( [query] => Array ( [post_type] => product [orderby] => rand [order] => desc [posts_per_page] => 4 [post__not_in] => Array ( [0] => 908 ) [meta_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => is_generic_cross_sell [compare] => == [value] => 1 ) ) )
```

But query_vars looks like:

```
 [query_vars] => Array ( [post_type] => product [orderby] => menu_order [order] => ASC [posts_per_page] => 4 [post__not_in] => Array ( [0] => 914 ) [meta_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => is_generic_cross_sell [compare] => == [value] => 1 ) )
```

i.e. orderby changes from "rand" to "menu_order".

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Try to add this parameter to the args array: "suppress_filters" => true,

Comment: @OfirBaruch Thanks but that hasn't made any difference. orderby still changes to "menu_order"

Comment: Is it possible you've made any modification in the WP library files (besides theme/plugin)?

Comment: @OfirBaruch No, BUT I checked the plugins after your question and realised we are using "Simple Custom Post Order" so that the client can rearrange products. I deactivated and now the random order works -- so that was the problem. Now I just need to figure out how to keep that plugin working without messing up the query. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the "Simple Custom Post Order" plugin.

Solution:
Replaced "Simple Custom Post Order" with "Post Types Order" (identical functionality). 
Update query to include:

```
"suppress_filters" => true
```

Query now returns random order but client can still drag and drop to rearrange product order in the backend.